# use object destructuring for react, trying to do pagination and add one to page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im trying to add one to page every time the bottom of the div is reaached, but i'm getting the folliwing error "use object destructuring" and im not sure how to fix this. Here is the following code

```js
 const vendorContainer = document.getElementById('vendorCard')!
    let loadingMore = false
    const pagination = {
      count: 50,
      page: 0
  }

vendorContainer.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      const scrollHeight = vendorContainer.scrollHeight
      const scrollTop = vendorContainer.scrollTop
      const clientHeight = vendorContainer.clientHeight
      if(((scrollTop + clientHeight) > scrollHeight - 200) && !loadingMore){
        loadingMore = true
        pagination.page += pagination.page + 1
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

It wants you to refactor these 3 lines:

```js
const scrollHeight = vendorContainer.scrollHeight
const scrollTop = vendorContainer.scrollTop
const clientHeight = vendorContainer.clientHeight
```

into

```js
const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = vendorContainer
```

See [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)